# Local AppStore currency for spesific price tier as variable?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization, app-store, currency

I'm trying to create a custom 'ad' for one of our own additional apps in appstore. Everything is working perfectly, but in the ad we are now writing `NSLog(@"For only $0.99");`
How can I make this a variable based on the local 'logged in' appstore? I'm thinking it should look something like this:

```
NSString *price = [something localPriceForTier:1];
NSLog(@"For only %@", price);
```

And it'd say whatever currency and value it is where the user is based on that the Price Tier I'm sending is 1. I think I've seen apps with this before, but I have no idea what to search for regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Store Kit doesn't have any function to ask for generic price tier. You have to ask for the current local price of one of your products. Here's some code:

```
- (void) requestProductData
{
    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:
            [NSSet setWithObject: yourProductIdentifier]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}
```

The callback function:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *myProducts = response.products;
    SKProduct *product = [myProducts objectAtIndex:0];
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
    NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];

    NSLog(@"For only %@", formattedString);
}
```

The above snippets are explained in detail in the official In-App Purchase Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267

Comment: So the 'pro' version has to be approved and be on AppStore for the 'lite' version to use this function?

Answer (score 1):

That information isn't kept on the device, it's something you have to fetch if you want it. So what you want to do is create an [`SKProductsRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProductsRequest/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008417) with the appropriate product identifiers (which you can get from iTunes Connect), wait until your delegate gets a suitable [`SKProductsResponse`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProductsResponse/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/SKProductsResponse) from which you can obtain the appropriate [`SKProduct`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKProduct) and you can use the `price` and `priceLocale` from there with a number formatter to get a string of the local price with the appropriate currency symbol. There's a quick bit of sample code in the `SKProduct` documentation.